# How to redirect stdin (specific file name) to stdout (specific file name)

Tags: c, shell, unix, dup2

I am creating a shell code. Basically, I want to redirect stdin file to stdout file. For instance when I enter a command like sort < hello.c > t.txt, then the hello.c file should be copied in new mentioned file called t.txt.

Here is my code, I am able to redirect output of other commands, when I type ls > t.txt. However, I don't have any idea about redirecting one file's input to other file using dup2.

Here is my code, I am only posting the loop, as this is where I have to create the logic.

```
int in, out;

for (i = 0; i < arridx; i++) {
    if(strcmp( array[i],"<")==0)
    {    
             in = open(array[i+1], O_RDONLY);        
             array[i]=0;
            // array[i+1]=0;
    }
    if(strcmp( array[i],">")==0)
    {
              out = open(array[i+1], O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IWUSR);
              array[i]=0;
             // array[i+1]=0;
    }
}
dup2(in, 0);
dup2(out, 1);

// close unused file descriptors
close(in);
close(out);
```

Input array would be like

```
array[0]="sort"
array[1]="<"
array[2]="hello.c"
array[3]=">"
array[4]="t.txt"
```

Comment: Your shell forks, and the child opens the file `hello.c` for reading, and the file `t.txt` for writing, and then arranges for the first file descriptor to be the standard input of `sort` and the second to be the standard output, before it executes `sort`.  The shell itself doesn't read or write the files.

Comment: I don't think you can afford to treat redirection that laxly.  If I write at the command line: `sort "<" "hello.c" ">" "t.txt"`, then the `sort` program needs to be handed 4 arguments, each of which is a file to be sorted.  Further, those quotes all need to be removed before the strings are passed to the `sort` program.  So, you can't readily tell whether I wrote I/O redirections or not just by looking at the arguments.  Your parser has to determine what to do with each argument, based on what it sees, and it will likely need to treat redirections separately from regular arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, whenever you run something like :

```
command < hello.c > t.txt
```

The redirection will take place presuming command is your argv[0] with no of arguments as 1, and redirection taking place by the shell.

However, on another point, going through your program, if redirection is used 
not from command prompt but by array contents only, 
`int dup2(int oldfd, int newfd);` - creates a copy of the file descriptor oldfd.
In your case,

```
dup2(in, 0);
dup2(out, 1);
```

0 and 1 stands for stdin and stdout file descriptors respectively. So, if you would like to redirect your input to be taken from the stdin instead of hello.c (file opened as in) and output to be taken from the stdout instead of t.txt (file opened as out), then shouldn't be other way round i.e.

```
dup2(0, in);
dup2(1, out);
```

Comment: Redirection is **not** done by the OS; it is done by the shell (at least in *nix)!